# Tricky Negative Binomial example

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Let $Y$ count the number of widgets succesfully produced before $r$th failure. We are told that machine shuts down when $30$th failure has occured, that is $r=30$. Then probability of producing $y$ widgets before machine shuts down is given by Negative Binomial pmf
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
y+r-1\\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
(1-p)^rp^y=\begin{pmatrix}
y+29\\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
(1-p)^{30}p^y .
\end{equation}
WHAT IS THE PROBABILITY THAT MACHINE SHUTS DOWN BEFORE PRODUCING 3 WIDGETS?

Firstly, I have tried to use the pmf of $Y$ in the following way.

$\mathbb{P}\Bigg( machine\ shuts\ down\ before\ 3\ widgets \Bigg)=\mathbb{P}(Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(Y=1)+\mathbb{P}(Y=2)$

that is the sum of probabilities that 0,1,2 widgets produced before machine shuts down.

Then I constructed random variable $X$ that counts failures before $r$th successes, that $X$ pmf is the same as $Y$, with difference of counting probabilities
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X=x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
x+r-1\\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
(1-p)^xp^r
\end{equation}

thus setting $r=3$ the required probability can be presented as
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X=30)=
\begin{pmatrix}
30+3-1\\ 30 
\end{pmatrix}
(1-p)^{30}p^3=\begin{pmatrix}
32\\ 30 
\end{pmatrix}
(1-p)^{30}p^3
\end{equation}

PROBLEM!!! The required probability calculated as the sum is NOT the same as one calculated using $X$.

ANY EXPLANATION WHERE DID I MISS THE POINT?

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* Although the formulation of the two approaches looks quite similar they describe *two different situations*.

Let's state the problem:

> **Problem:** A machine producing widgets shuts down when the $30$th failure has occured ($r=30$). The probability of producing a widget without failure is $p$. What is the probability that the machine shuts down *before* producing 3 widgets?
>
> **First approach:**
>
> We have to keep in mind *two crucial aspects* of the problem
>
> - The machine *terminates* with the $30$th failure
> - There are $0,1$ or $2$ widgets which may be successfully produced *before* the terminating event occurs
>
> We conclude:
>
> Due to the *termination* with the $30$th failure we have *event chains* of length exactly $30,31$ or $32$ depending on $0,1$ or $2$ successfully produced widgets.
>
> Since the last terminating event is always a failure event, we have *event chains* of length $29, 30$ or $31$ where we may distribute $0,1$ or $2$ sucessfully produced widgets, leaving the last event with probability $1-p$ for a failure event.
>
> Let $Y\in\{0,1,2\}$ be a random variable denoting the number of successfully produced widgets. We get:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{P}(Y=0)=\binom{29}{0}p^0(1-p)^{30}\\
> \mathbb{P}(Y=1)=\binom{30}{1}p^1(1-p)^{30}\\
> \mathbb{P}(Y=2)=\binom{31}{2}p^2(1-p)^{30}\\
> \end{align*}

These formulae correspond to the *negative binomial distribution*

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y=y)&=\binom{y+r-1}{y }p^y(1-p)^r\\
&=\binom{y+29}{y}p^y(1-p)^{30} \qquad \qquad y\in\{0,1,2\}
\end{align*}

> and the (correct) result is according to this approach:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(Y=0)+\mathbb{P}(Y=1)+\mathbb{P}(Y=2)$$

---

> **Second approach:**
>
> Now, let $X$ be a random variable counting the *number of failures* **before** the $r$-th success. Let's further consider the expression:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X=30)=\binom{32}{2}p^3(1-p)^{30}=\left(\binom{32}{2}p^2(1-p)^{30}\right)\cdot p\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

> We observe, the RHS of (1) counts the number of *event chains* of length $33$, whereby exactly two successes and $30$ failures occur giving $\binom{32}{2}$ possibilities, **before** the $3$rd success with probability $p$ happens.

*Attention:* This approach contradicts the crucial aspects from above which we have to follow:

> - When focusing on the *event chains* up to the $32$nd event (*before the $3$rd success*) we have no longer *necessarily* the situation, that the terminating $32nd$ event is a *failure*. The **termination condition** is violated.
> - We observe that since the last event of the event-chain of length $32$ can be either a failure or success we erroneously count as follows
>     \begin{equation*}
>   \binom{32}{2}=
>   \begin{cases}
>   \binom{31}{1}&\text{last event is a success}\\
>   +&\\
>   \binom{31}{2}&\text{last event is a failure}\\
>   \end{cases}
>   \end{equation*}
> - Furthermore the **length conditions** having length $30,31,32$ (including the terminating failure event) of the event chains from above are also violated. *Filling* the smaller chains at the right end with *success events* in (1) is not a proper substitute, since we then erroneously also multiply with $p^3$ which is not correct.

*Conclusion:* The second approach does not properly describe the above stated problem.